# How to sum string value in lodash by particular column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash, angular7

Hi there i am using lodash for aggregation purpose but i have stuck at one place i am getting my value as a string instead of float so its concate rather then summing the value.

Below is the way tried.

```
var data = [{extendedPrice: "5151.059", month: "January"}, 
            {extendedPrice: "8921.0336", month: "March"},
            {extendedPrice: "2036.9865", month: "April"}];

var sumValue = _.sumBy(data,extendedPrice);
```

The result from above

> 5151.0598921.03362036.9865

Expected Result:

> 16109.0791

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Issue because of the string values. Please use parseInt or Number at the callback.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since the values are strings, the `+` means concatenation, not addition. You can supply a callback to the `_.sumBy` function:

```
_.sumBy(data, item => Number(item.extendedPrice));
```

Working demo:

```js
var data = [{extendedPrice: "5151.059", month: "January"}, 
            {extendedPrice: "8921.0336", month: "March"},
            {extendedPrice: "2036.9865", month: "April"}];

var sumValue = _.sumBy(data, item => Number(item.extendedPrice));
console.log(sumValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, buddy it really saved my hour, if i want to group by month + sum it with extendedPrice how that can be done, if you can help ?

Comment: @Mayur -- Use `_.groupBy` first to group by the month, and then for each group, use `_.sumBy` like I mentioned.

Comment: is i need to chain these or there is some other way

Comment: @Mayur -- you may do anything as you prefer.